# Можно ли настроить WooCommerce так, чтобы после нажатия кнопки "Купить" перекидывало сразу на форму оформления заказа, минуя корзину

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Хочу сделать отдельную продающую страницу с только одним товаром, нужно это для рекламы в FB. Сайт работает на WordPress, установлен плагин Woocommerce. Есть ли возможность настроить эту страницу так, чтобы товар не добавлялся в корзину, а клиента сразу перекинуло на страницу оформления заказа?

Comment: Зачем вам Woocommerce для одного товара?

Comment: Мы продаем не только один товар, но для одного я хочу сделать продающий лп и рекламировать его, но для этого я хочу избавится от корзины, но принимать и обрабатывать платежи как-то хотелось бы.

Answer (score 2):

В настройках Woocommerce, вкладка Товары поставьте галку

> Перенаправить в корзину после успешного добавления

А на странице Корзины замените шорткод с `[woocommerce_cart]` на `[woocommerce_checkout]`